# Java Generics - How do I call a generic map with a successor object

Tags: java, generics

I wrote the following method

```
 validate(Map<String,IAnimal> map)
```

And I want to call it with

```
dogMap = new HashMap<String,Dog>;
...
validate(dogMap)
```

where Dog is the successor of Animal,
But it does not compile.
How do I change it so I could call it with a successor object?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the signature of `validate` to :

```
validate(Map<String,? extends IAnimal> map)
```

This will allow you to pass any map with a `String` key and a value that extends or implements `IAnimal`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare the method with type boundaries:

```
validate(Map<String,? extends IAnimal> map)
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html for further explanations of Java (Bounded) Wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Change the signature of `validate` to `YourReturnType validate(Map<? extends String, ? extends IAnimal> map)` (assuming you do not want to add elements to it).
2. Create a new `Map<String, IAnimal>` from the `dogMap` you want to pass: `new HashMap<String, IAnimal>(dogMap)` and pass that object to `validate`.

Comment: `? extends SomeFinalClass` is redundant for any final class; `String` is a final class.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Well, it prevents `put`, `putAll`, ... with other than `null`, so it is a signal that the method do not intend to add new items.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Not for the key. ;) Value can be `null`, with `? extends String` the only valid option for the key will be `null` too.

Comment: True, still the benefit is quite dubious since inserting `null, null` is just as bad if not worse than inserting some legal key. So you don't actually guarantee anything interesting.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, I know, it is just a signal. (Which has no effect for `get` or `remove` or `Iterator#remove`) One can just cast to raw type and then to any other `Map`, so it will not bring unescapeable type safety, but when the next maintainer of the lib tries to `put` to the input map and see on completion the only option is `null, null` (s)he might think/ask why was it the reason or consult the comments. This is my personal preference though.

Comment: Ah, you actually do that in your code, and for that particular reason? I thought you came up with it just to have something to offer in its defence :) In that case, +1 for your answer.