# Is there a way to send a list/map of a concrete type to a method that recieves a list/map of interfaces?

Tags: java, generics

Is there a way to send a list/map of a concrete type to a method that recieves a list/map of interfaces?

e.g. 
(`Toyota extends Car` and `Car implements ICar`)

I want to call

```
private static void doSomething(Map<String, ICar> cars) {}
```

Using

```
Map<String, Toyota> toyotas = new HashMap<>();
doSomething0(toyotas);
```

Comment: No you can't, [Generics are invariant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant)

Comment: You asked basically the same thing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186926/java-why-does-sending-concrete-implementation-to-a-generic-interaface-as-param and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28136383/java-generics-how-do-i-call-a-generic-map-with-a-successor-object . The answer won't change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use type bounds :

```
private static void doSomething(Map<String, ? extends ICar> cars) {}
```

Example :

```
public static void doSomething (Map<String,? extends Number> numMap)
{
    for (Number n : numMap.values ())
         System.out.println (n);
}

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Map<String,Integer> intMap = new HashMap<String, Integer> ();
    intMap.put("two",2);
    intMap.put("three",3);
    doSomething (intMap);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your declaration to:

```
private static void doSomething(Map<String, ? extends ICar> cars) {}
```

This means acept everything that extends `ICar`.